# How do I get the drop down with image and name in select option using ionic framework?

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to list country's in select option with country flag.
Solution please

Comment: Solution please? You should start by reading the [ask] page, please.

Comment: Share some lines of code which you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Destination</label>
<input type="text" name="cdCountry" class="form-control" required />
```

```
<script>
$("[name='cdCountry']").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a country",
    formatResult: function (country) {
        return $(
          "<span><i class=\"flag flag-" + country.id.toLowerCase() + "\"></i> " + country.text + "</span>"
        );;
    },
    data: yourDataSource
});
```

And ya please dont forget to use the css library (css and a sprite) https://www.flag-sprites.com/